# NSOutlineView selected item move

Tags: macos, cocoa, nsoutlineview

I have an `NSOutlineView` which has two groups and select one item when init. When I click HeaderCell and let one group collapse and the other expand, the selected item moves to the next group. Why does this happen?

How can I improve this and make the selected item not move?

update:
this happens when the cell move outside the `NSOutlineView`.So I guess the problem is that the cell reuse.

update:
before

[image]

after:

[image]

update:
The problem is that the `NSOutlineView`'s index of row changes when the outlineview collapses or expands.

Comment: @Monolo,thanks,my English is poor.

Comment: Can you post 2 screenshots, before and after you click.

Comment: Where did you click?  And what is the result you want?  Since `Mozilla Fire...` has disappeared, what row do you want selected now? Or do you want no selection?  How are you making `Folder` collapse when you select `Color Tag`?  Are you observing `NSOutlineViewItemDidExpandNotification`?

Comment: it selects TopList when init.And then I click Mozilla Fire.. and the third click the Folder .At this time the NSOutlineView collapse,and the GrayColor is selected.

Comment: In the NSOutlineView's delegate method outlineView:viewForTableColumn:item: I use selectRowIndexes:byExtendingSelection:. I guess its the problem.